# How does python's logging module work with calls to logger within function imported from main to subprocess?

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, pipe

So basically I have a setup similar to the following:

A main program:

```
`# mainprogram.py
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(processName)s] %(message)s'))
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def func ():
   # do something 
   log.debug("Some message")

def main ():
   func
   log.debug("beginning subprocess")
   with subprocess.Popen(subprogram.py, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) as proc:
      # do something with proc's in- & outputs
   log.debug("main is done")

if "__main__" == __name__:
   main()`
```

and a subprogram which I start via the main program using the `subprocess` module:

```
# subprogram.py
from mainprogram import func

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('[%(processName)s] %(message)s'))
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

log.debug("subprocess started")
func
log.debug("subprocess done")`
```

Now somehow I always get the following pattern printed to the screen:

```
[MainProcess] <some text here>
```

My question:
since subprocess's stdin and stdout, but nor stderr are piped and the StreamHandler was setup with it's default arguments, each logger should have a unique handler and print to the terminal via stderr. Why do I keep getting the main program as "owner" of the log message?

thanks in advance

Changing the formatter's `processName` to `filename` results in the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Александр Слабкин pointed out, the `__name__` and process name are not unique. What is unique is the logger's name, the filename, and the process ID. To demonstrate that, I have modified your scripts as such:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# mainprogram.py
import logging
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

log = logging.getLogger("main")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter("[%(name)s:%(filename)s:%(process)d] %(message)s")
)

log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def func(msg):
    # do something
    log.debug(msg)


def main():
    func("call from mainprogram [1]")
    log.debug("beginning subprocess [2]")
    with subprocess.Popen(
        ["python3", "subprogram.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, text=True
    ) as proc:
        pass
    log.debug("main is done [6]")


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

and

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# subprogram.py
import logging
from mainprogram import func


log = logging.getLogger("sub")
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(
    logging.Formatter("[%(name)s:%(filename)s:%(process)d] %(message)s")
)
log.addHandler(handler)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


def main():
    """Entry"""
    log.debug("subprocess started [3]")
    func("call from subprogram [4]")
    log.debug("subprocess done [5]")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[main:mainprogram.py:63585] call from mainprogram [1]
[main:mainprogram.py:63585] beginning subprocess [2]
[sub:subprogram.py:63586] subprocess started [3]
[main:mainprogram.py:63586] call from subprogram [4]
[sub:subprogram.py:63586] subprocess done [5]
[main:mainprogram.py:63585] main is done [6]
```

#### Comments on Output Lines

- 1, 2: no surprise here
- 3: Note how the logger name is now "sub" and the process ID changed
- 4: Notice that the logger name is "main", the log line happens in mainprogram.py, but the process ID belongs to subprogram.py
- 5, 6: no surprise here

#### Summary

What you thought as "owner" are just the name of `__main__`, and the name of the process. These are not unique. My code demonstrate that you indeed have two different loggers and two different processes which create these loggers.

Comment: That cleared things up, thank you. It raises a follow up question though: so importing `func` does not simply copy code from mainprogram to subprogram but also somehow keeps information about where this piece of code came from. Because `log` is a global variable in both programs, but using it within the imported function, the module's name in which it was originally defined showes up

Answer (score 1):

When you call a script, its name replaced with `__main__`. This is how `if __name__ == '__main__'` structure works.
Apparently, similar thing is happening with `processName`.

When you call it as a subprocess the behavior is close to calling it directly as a main script. For a new interpreter, which is created in a subprocess, this script is becoming main, and interpreter treats it accordingly.
Here is a small example:

```py
inner.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print(f'inner {__name__=}')
    
outer.py:
import subprocess    
print(f'outer {__name__=}')
subprocess.Popen('./inner.py')

output:
python3 outer.py 
outer __name__='__main__'
inner __name__='__main__'
```

Have you tried to log process id in formatter instead: `%(process)d`?